# Android cursor move selected to the top

Tags: android

I have a listview that is populated by data from [ContactsContract.RawContacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html), and I want to have some items to be selected when presented to the user. Is it possible to move the selected items to the top of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Since add view to a specific location in `ListView` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. We couldn't add or remove in the list view directly, but you could try to get current selected position data, and rearrange the position in adapter's data to the first place. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged` to update your list view.

Comment: @Hank It could be done by cursor adapter, but you have to rearrange the data order retrieved from your sqlite database.

Comment: Which method in the cursoradapter would I need to change to rearrange the data?

Comment: It's not easy to be done with cursor adapter. you can try sql query clause `order by _column` when you build the cursor adapter. But i suggest you use a second adapter, this adapter hold the data from sqlite database and populate data to the listview, then you can rearrange the data in this adapter or do whatever you want.